# Display information from metabox

Tags: plugins

I have this plugin that sets a minimum and a maximum quantity that you can order for each product. I would like to get the Minimum quantity from the plugin and display as text under my add to cart button. I have added the function at the end of the code "//// Display minimum quantity" but this is not working. Any help?

Here is the plugin code:

```
<?php
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wc_mmax_meta_box_create');
add_action('save_post', 'wc_mmax_save_meta_box');
function wc_mmax_meta_box_create()
{
    add_meta_box('wc_mmax_enable', __('Min Max Quantity', 'wcmmax'), 'wc_mmax_meta_box', 'product', 'side');
}

function wc_mmax_meta_box($post)
{
    wp_nonce_field('wc_mmax_cst_prd_nonce', 'wc_mmax_cst_prd_nonce');

    echo '<p>';
    echo '<label for="_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable" style="float:left; width:50px;">' . __('Enable', 'wcmmax') . '</label>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable" value="0" />';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable" class="checkbox" name="_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable" value="1" ' . checked(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable', true), 1, false) . ' />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    $max = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wc_mmax_max', true);
    $min = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wc_mmax_min', true);
    echo '<label for="_wc_mmax_min" style="float:left; width:50px;">' . __('Min Quantity', 'wcmmax') . '</label>';
    echo '<input type="number" id="_wc_mmax_min" class="short" name="_wc_mmax_min" value="' . $min . '" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<label for="_wc_mmax_max" style="float:left; width:50px;">' . __('Max Quantity', 'wcmmax') . '</label>';
    echo '<input type="number" id="_wc_mmax_max" class="short" name="_wc_mmax_max" value="' . $max . '" />';
    echo '</p>';

}

function wc_mmax_save_meta_box($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;
    if (!isset($_POST['_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wc_mmax_cst_prd_nonce'], 'wc_mmax_cst_prd_nonce'))
        return;
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable', (int) $_POST['_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_wc_mmax_max',(int) $_POST['_wc_mmax_max']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_wc_mmax_min', (int) $_POST['_wc_mmax_min']);
}



function wc_mmax_remove_loop_button()
{
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
}
add_action('init', 'wc_mmax_remove_loop_button');


add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_mmax_replace_add_to_cart');
function wc_mmax_replace_add_to_cart()
{
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    echo '';
}


/*Function to manipulate custom minimum and maximum purchase*/
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'wc_mmax_quantity_input_args', 10, 2);
function wc_mmax_quantity_input_args($args, $product)
{
if(function_exists('icl_object_id')) {
    $default_language = wpml_get_default_language();
    $prodid = icl_object_id($product->get_id(), 'product', true, $default_language);
} else {
    $prodid = $product->id;
}
    $mmaxEnable = get_post_meta($prodid, '_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable', true);
    $minQty     = get_post_meta($prodid, '_wc_mmax_min', true);
    $maxQty     = get_post_meta($prodid, '_wc_mmax_max', true);
    if ($minQty > 0 && $maxQty > 0 && $mmaxEnable == 1) {
        $args['min_value'] = $minQty; // Starting value
        $args['max_value'] = $maxQty; // Ending value
    }
 return $args;

}
/*Function to check weather the maximum quantity is already existing in the cart*/

add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'wc_mmax_custom_add_to_cart',10,2);

function wc_mmax_custom_add_to_cart($args,$product)
{
    $orderQTY = $_POST['quantity'];
    $mmaxEnable = get_post_meta($product, '_wc_mmax_prd_opt_enable', true);
    $minQty     = get_post_meta($product, '_wc_mmax_min', true);
    $maxQty     = get_post_meta($product, '_wc_mmax_max', true);
    $cartQty =  wc_mmax_woo_in_cart($product);

if($maxQty < $cartQty && $mmaxEnable == 1)
{
echo "
<script>
alert('".__('You have already added the maximum Quantity for the product for the current purchase','wcmax')."');
location.href='". get_permalink($product)."';
</script>";

exit();
}

if(($orderQTY + $cartQty)  < $minQty && $mmaxEnable == 1)
{
echo "
<script>
alert('".__('Ai comandat '.$orderQTY.' bucati. Numarul minim de bucati ce poate fi comandat este de '.$minQty.'','wcmax')."');
location.href='". get_permalink($product)."';
</script>";

exit();
}

}

function wc_mmax_woo_in_cart($product_id) {
    global $woocommerce;
    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {

        $_product = $val['data'];
        if($product_id == $_product->get_id()) {


        return  $val['quantity'];

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
//// Display minimum quantity
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {

echo '<div class="second_content" style="margin-top: 20px; padding-top: 20px;" >Minimum order quantity is: '.$minQty.'  </div>';
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `$minQty` is not defined in the scope of the `add_content_after_addtocart_button_func()` function ;)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to define the function this way but is not working... add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
    $minQty     = get_post_meta($product, '_wc_mmax_min', true);
 if($maxQty > 0) {

echo '<br><div class="second_content" style="margin-top: 20px; padding-top: 20px;" >Minimum order quantity is: '.$minQty.'  </div>';
  }
}

Comment: And here `$product` is not defined. What if you add `global $product;` at the beginning of this function?

Comment: Added but still not displaying anything... It looks like this now: add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
 global $product;
    $minQty     = get_post_meta($product, '_wc_mmax_min', true);
 if($minQty > 0) {

echo '<br><div class="second_content" style="margin-top: 20px; padding-top: 20px;" >Minimum order quantity is: '.$minQty.'  </div>';
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the soulution:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_min_quantity',10,2);
function wc_min_quantity($product)
{
if(function_exists('icl_object_id')) {
    $default_language = wpml_get_default_language();
    $prodid = icl_object_id($product->get_id(), 'product', true, $default_language);
  } else {
      $prodid = $product->id;
  }
  $prodid = get_the_ID();
  $minQty     = get_post_meta($prodid, '_wc_mmax_min', true);
  if ($minQty > 0) {
  }

  echo "Minimum order quantity: $minQty";

}
```